# std::find_if and a lambda - error void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that uses `std::find_if` and a lamda function to check entries in a tuple.

If the third entry in the tuple is not a `nullptr` then add the first entry in the tuple (the string) to the list and return the list.

However, compilations fails with

> /usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:234:30: error: void value not
>   ignored as it ought to be   { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }

Could anybody identify what im doing wrong?

```
std::vector<std::string> class::list() const
{
    std::vector<std::string> arglist;
    arglist.reserve((arguments_.size()));

    std::find_if(arguments_.begin(), arguments_.end(),[&arglist](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Value> argument)
        {
            if (&std::get<2>(argument) != nullptr)
                arglist.push_back(std::get<0>(argument));
        }
    );
    return arglist;
}
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required please!

Comment: It's complaining that your predicate isn't a predicate.

Comment: Also, you'll probably want to use `std::for_each` or `std::transform` instead.

Comment: did you read any documentation on `std::find_if` ? It seems like your expectations have nothing to do what it actually does

Comment: to avoid the unfortunately too frequent misunderstanding: I am not trying to be clever or rude, I just think it would help if you explained what you expected `std::find_if` to do. (...and yes, I think it would help if you read some documentation before you ask a quesiton, which maybe you did, we dont know...)

Comment: By the way, what is `Value`? It seems to me that the condition `&std::get<2>(argument) != nullptr` will *always* be true, but without knowing what `Value` is it's impossible to say.

Comment: What type is `arguments_`?

Comment: Also, `argument` should be passed by reference, not by value

Answer (score 7):

The predicate should not really perform any actions, only return a `true` or `false` depending on if the searched for item matches your condition or not.

Your lambda doesn't return anything, which leads to the error you get.

---

It seems to me that what you really want is [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) or [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each). Or even just a plain [ranged `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)?

Comment: So that's merely a simple (typo) problem?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I don't think so, as it looks like the OP is attempting to do some action instead of finding something.